# No se puede enlazar a 'ngForOf' ya que no es una propiedad conocida de 'ion-item'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic, ngfor

Ya e probado distintas soluciones y aun no e dado con la solucion
He probado casi todas las soluciones presentes, algunos dicen que es error en los imports y los he comprobado y todos están correctos

.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Pizarra
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ion-label>{{item.tipo_tarjeta_url}}</ion-label> <br>
      <ion-label>{{item.cant}}</ion-label> <br>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit{
  items : any;
  constructor(
   

  ) {

    
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```

Tengo todos los imports de modules hechos y aun persiste el error.

Este es el fichero modulo de la pagina que me esta provocando el conficto

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';

import { HomePageRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    HomePageRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Esta es mi fichero modulo principal
app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Ahi estan tambien los modules.ts de mi proyecto.
Estan importado tanto el BrowserModule como elComonModule, y aun asi me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Agrego la info de ionic por si es algun problema de estos

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1101.4
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.2.3
@angular/cli                  : 11.1.4
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.0

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed
System:ve-run  : not installed

NodeJS : v15.5.1
npm    : 7.3.0
OS     : Windows 10

Comment: trata de inicializar `items` dentro del constructor

Comment: aun persiste el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decidi actualizar todos los componentes y programas que utilizo, como npm, angular/cli e ionic y ya me lo reconoce, al parecer era algun conflicto con alguna de estas versiones que tenia

Answer (score 1):

Es necesario que en tu módulo principal agregues uno de los dos siguientes imports "BrowserModule" o "CommonModule" dentro de la directiva @NgModule() en el array de imports.

Comment: estan agregados, pero aun asi no lo reconoce

Comment: podrías compartir un ejemplo de tu código o la configuración de tu módulo?

Comment: edite la publicacion agregando los 2 ficheros